# Looking for an article about eruv

Tags: shabbat, product-recommendation, publications, eruv-chatzerot

I'm looking for an article, that covers every aspects, bits and pieces about the eruv that lets people carry on Shabbat. Sources, history, contemporary situation, so on.

Answer (score 5):

Every aspect? It doesn't exist, sorry.

There's an entire tractate of the Talmud one of whose two main topics is this kind of *eruv*. Plus all the commentaries on that tractate, law codes, commentaries on the codes, and so on. I'm sure there's no article that covers it all.

Comment: Unless you call the entire tractate of the Talmud plus its commentaries (etc.) to be an article.

Comment: But I guess that doesn't cover the contemporary situation. It also doesn't address the _eruv_ in Columbus, OH, which would be a prerequisite for an article of the scope the OP is asking about.

Comment: Eruvin is perhaps the hardest Massechet

Comment: There are very few m'forshim on Eruvin.  The only well known one bein g'on yaakov. Even on Shulchan Aruch the pischai tshuva quotes very few tshuvos. The MB is also not very much. He says he will discuss a "park" in a later siman and doesnt.  The only one who does is the Chazon Ish.  Most eruvin today, even in Israel do not follow the CI saying old eruvin like Miron dont follow him.  There are two talmidai chachmim today (one who wrote Eshed hancholim) who are the world experts and make most of the eruvin today and also dont follow the CI.  This is more or less the "contemporary" situation.

Comment: Very surprisingly the original English artscroll on Eruvin brings a  CI but the later smaller daf yomi edition missed it out.  I am referring to daf 24b.

Comment: I think, someone like Hafetz Chaim could do such a book!!! 
Even Shulhan Aruch has the short version! And that shortened version has its own excerpts, rehearsals and briefs!

Comment: @UlrikheLukoie, but you asked for **every** aspect.

Comment: @msh210 yes. and i really think it is possible to archive! so i thought maybe someone already have done that.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to search Google Books for "Eruv."

E.g., [Contemporary Eruv by Bechhofer (2002)](https://books.google.com/books?isbn=1583300139)