# Watching Movies nowadays

Tags: halacha

Is one allowed to watch movies (i.e. on his tv), today?

Since they portray:

• Women not dressed modestly.

• Affections between men and women

If one does watch a movie, is he transgressing any Torah prohibitions?

Comment: Here's a movie by a rabbi https://vimeo.com/155998963 Seemingly he thinks it's ok to watch his own movie. Here's another by a different rabbi https://vimeo.com/155584669

Comment: @DoubleAA, did they know they were being filmed? If not, it's no proof. (Note: I haven't watched the movies to find out, since movies portray women not dressed modestly and affections between men and women.)

Comment: @msh210 As is their way, DoubleAA was being sarcastic

Comment: @Yehoshua, I was kidding, actually. I don't really think a movie of a _shiur_ by Rabbi Pliskin or Leff portrays women not dressed modestly. I think DoubleAA's point was that the question was asked too broadly to be answerable except by "depends on the movie, and here's how..." (which is not a bad thing, but is *probably* not the question the asker meant to ask). He could've made that point more directly in addition to linking to an example of it, but that means he was being oblique, not sarcastic. I agree obliquity is a bar to communication.

Comment: @msh210 Was it more or less oblique than the message at http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/71097/759

Comment: @DoubleAA, about the same in intent `:-)` but as it turned out my answer there is exactly what the asker had been seeking (see his/her latter comment thereon).

Comment: Duplicate? http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/45168/6886

Comment: @ray You should consider adding a whitelist to your filter for anything written by a *gadol hador*.

Comment: @ray Your ISP should whitelist pages with the names of gedolei hador on them or, more specifically, whitelist Mi Yodeya and other Judaism sites.

Answer (score 1):

Igrot Moshe Even Ha-Ezer Vol.1 56, by Rabbi [Moshe Feinstein](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moshe_Feinstein) (translation from [here](https://books.google.co.il/books?id=Tg1e9NoOOKQC&pg=PA88)):

> Since the prohibition is meant to prevent erotic thought, one is
>   entitled to rely upon his own ability to divert his mind from such
>   thought when he has to go somewhere for such things as his livelihood.
>   He is not obligated to make a financial sacrifice or to neglect his
>   other needs. Only when he has no need to pass, as when there is
>   another route, or when he is only going on an outing, even if there is
>   no other route, is he forbidden to rely upon his ability to divert his
>   mind. This is the prohibition of "Guard yourself from every evil
>   thing." One should not without cause rely upon one's own ability to
>   evoid erotic thought...

this probably applies in surfing the internet also for certain sites